# how to navigate to the cell where a user-custom function is defined?

Tags: front-end, cells

For a large notebook involving many custom functions, I often feel helpless in locating their definitions: there seems to lack an easy to locate the definition of a function.

On the contrary, for example, when writing Python in VS Code, one can easily navigate to the beginning line of a function's definition by `alt`+click the function name.

Meanwhile, I'm aware that in Mathematica we do have multiple ways (e.g. `Definition`, `Information`, etc.) to show the definition of a function.

However, I'm just wondering if I can quickly navigate to the cell where a given function is defined to facilitate editing, etc.?

Comment: You can do this manually using cell tags and notebooklocate[]

Comment: Unfortunately, any given function may be defined multiple times in multiple cells. Despite this, if you have a "Package" (*.wl or *.m) file there is a drop down "Functions" menu listing the functions and when you click on one it takes you there.

Comment: If you have in mind the notebook that has been already evaluated and all functions are active, it is easy to recall them. One only needs to type the sign of the question (?) and then the function head. For example, let us define the function `f[x_] := x;` and now evaluate `?f`. The definition of the function will be returned. Another story is when the notebook has not been evaluated yet, or only evaluated partially. Then I do not know the answer.

Comment: thanks folks for the workarounds. it seems what I asked doesn't fit into the paradigm  of Mathematica for function definition.

Comment: It's possible. `Package.nb` provides a tool in its DockedCell to locate definitions. For more utilities like what you have seen in VSCode, you may need to write a function on your own and add a menu command for it.

Comment: thanks @rnotlnglgq, what is `Package.nb`? can you please provide more information of it?

Comment: But I did not implement it even if I have a idea. Because I've bound a key for ```GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinition```, which is more convenient in Mathematica.

Comment: @sunt05 It's a stylesheet. When you create a new package notebook with clicking the menu command `File/Package/Package`, the stylesheet of the new notebook will be set as `Package.nb`.